# Calculate width and padding in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically calculate the width and padding-left within a custom div within a bootstrap "container-fluid".

The setup looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
<!-- Text - Slider component -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 text"></div>
        <div class="col-6 slider"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- Text - Slider component -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-to-line-up-with">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, totam.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Within the text-slider component I would like the col-6 "text" to lineup with the text asif it lives in the regular 'container'.

I understand that I need to use some sort of calc() for the padding-left and width, but I can't wrap my head around this.

Any help or suggestions are very much welcome!

Disclaimer, this is an old project, which is still using bootstrap 3, and I can't change the html structure.

[I also made a codepen to give a better picture](https://codepen.io/sanderscheijbeler/pen/GRgrOGa)

Comment: Hmmm I don't think this is really possible. Your padding would have to be a fixed value (as it can't be a percentage) so it's won't line up as soon as the width changes.

Comment: Also your Codepen has a different structure to your code above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to calculate the width. The solution can be much easier with simply adding linear-gradient to your container-fluid background.

The HTML code structrure looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid red-blue py-4">
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis dolorem, non officiis aperiam facilis dicta fugiat velit obcaecati rerum odio quo a!</div>
        <div class="col-6 blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis dolorem, non officiis aperiam facilis dicta fugiat velit obcaecati rerum odio quo a!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis dolorem, non officiis aperiam facilis dicta fugiat velit obcaecati rerum odio quo a!</div>
    <div class="col-6 blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis dolorem, non officiis aperiam facilis dicta fugiat velit obcaecati rerum odio quo a!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.red-blue {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, blue 50%,blue 100%);  
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Hope this helps.